# React-native shadow props for android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Is there any way to render shadow as in web in react native, using elevation most of the times does not fits all the needs and shadow props only work for IOS, is there any react native builtin way to handle shadow props in android, if no then please suggest good light weight packages for shadow props must be easy to  use.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadow properties in react-native applies only on iOS. For Android you should set elevation property in your view style.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my **react-native-simple-shadow-view**

- This enables almost identical shadow in Android as in iOS
- No need to use elevation, works with the same shadow parameters of iOS (shadowColor, shadowOpacity, shadowRadius, offset, etc.) so you don't need to write platform specific shadow styles
- Can be used with semi-transparent views
- Supported in android 18 and up

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use this code to make shadow in android:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  myShadow: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    //flex: 1,
    height:50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 4,
  },
});
```

inside the render you can use like this:

```
render() {
<View style={styles.myShadow}/>
}
```

Comment: as far as I know this is perfect for ios but won't change anything for android

Comment: @AmmarTariq: elevation which exist inside the answer is for android.

Comment: you are elevation is for android, my question is elevation autogenerates shadow is there a way to manipulate it on android?

Answer (score 0):

For android, the elevation property does not work very well, I recommand this lib,
the style works the same as on ios:
[react-native-shadow-view](https://github.com/pinqy520/react-native-shadow-view)

Answer (score 0):

***Best way to provide shadow in Android and Ios both application in react native***

```css
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
 width: 0,
 height: 2,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.25,
shadowRadius: 3.84,

elevation: 5,
```

[image]
***Link : https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/***